# Script resulting in "OFF" value in output field due to off state of check box

Tags: javascript, pdf, checkbox

For most part this script works fine, it checks if Check Box4 is checked and if it is, it results in a calculation of Level + Check Box4 thru 7. The problem occurs that if any of Check Box5, 6 or 7 check boxes are in an off state, the calculatiuon returns the word "OFF" into the field as their output. The calculation still works but visibly this is bad.

Advice on how to retreive the on value but ignore the off value of a check box would be appreciated.

```
<code>
var v1 = this.getField("Check Box4").value;
if (v1 /= "") {
   event.value = this.getField("Level").value
 + this.getField("Check Box4").value
 + this.getField("Check Box5").value
 + this.getField("Check Box6").value
 + this.getField("Check Box7").value; }
if (isNaN(v1) || v1 === "") {event.value = "0";}
</code>
```

[screen shot of resulting yuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaa4J.png)

I wish we could set both on (2) and an off (0) value to a check box... :(

Comment: why pdf as tag ??? really ?

Comment: Could you please add the markup for the form. This probably has to do with handling the type of data from input field.

Comment: it's tagged as PDF because this java goes in a pdf, there is no form fields, it's gui in the pdf...

Answer (score 0):

You can either check if the `checked` value equals `true` to see if a checkbox is checked.

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('check');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', event => {
  if (event.target.checked === true) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="checkbox" value="check it out"/>
```

Or use the [`FormData API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) on submit to check all the values in a form. Only when a checkbox is checked it is included in the FormData collection, and vice versa.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  for (const [ name, value ] of formData) {
    console.log(name, value);
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="agreed" value="Yes" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="declined" value="No" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Dang, forgot to mention that this java is for a PDF form, not a web page. tyaw